# unable to add files with git add

Tags: git, version-control, git-add, git-status, git-stage

I have tried to git add a file. But when I check git status, the file is still marked as "Changes not staged for commit".
I have read many similar questions and I have tried everything:

- make sure I am in the right repository
- make sure there is no other .git in any folders (no submodules)
- make sure there is no corresponding entry in .gitignore (neither local nor global/system)
- make sure there is no upper/lower-case mistake
- make sure to try all variations of git add (-A, -u, ., *)

Still nothing seems to work

That is what it looks like:

[image]

Any ideas, what else to try or what I may have missed?

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT:**

This whole `_build/` folder is created, when I run `jb-build systemtechnik-fuer-energieeffizienz`. It contains (mainly, besides some other stuff, like these `.doctree` documents) the html output of a jupyter book created by all these jupyter notebooks in the `nb/` folder (see here [jupyter book](https://jupyterbook.org/start/build.html)). So it is not a submodule (in my understanding submodules have an own `.git` folder, however, inside `_build/` there is no such folder)

- The output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` is:

  `C:/Users/andre/Documents/GitLab/OER4EE_SYE/systemtechnik-fuer-energieeffizienz`
- `git version` is `git version 2.24.0.windows.2`
- the output of `git diff -- _build/.doctree/SYE.doctree`
  is:

  just a blank line
- the output of `git check-attr -a _build/.doctree/SYE.doctree` is:

  just another blank line

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`?

Comment: What *is* `_build/.doctrees/SYE/doctree`? Is it a submodule? (If so, you have a rather old version of Git.) (Note: your question would be *far* more readable if it were not largely an image of text. See [ask].)

Comment: Have you trie `git add _build/.doctrees/SYE.doctree`? If that doesn‘t work either, check if you execute the commands in the git-root folder (directory, where the `.git` folder is)

Comment: Also : what shows up in the diff with the indexed version `git diff -- _build/.doctree/...` ?

Comment: git can apply some modifications on a file when you run `git add`, if it has a `filter` attribute defined in `.gitattributes`. You can check your `.gitattributes` file in your repo, or run `git check-attr -a _build/.doctree/SYE.doctree` to see if any attribute applies to this file.

Comment: @torek: thank you for the hint! I will try to improve my question! Edit ahead

Comment: Aha. Probably the doctree file has some otherwise-invisible character(s) (newlnes, carriage returns, etc) that provide an end-of-line that your Windows system doesn't like very much, so that your Git is converting these to pure-CRLF line endings (generally preferred on Windows though there are exceptions). This is leading to a file that doesn't "add" properly. But, as in VonC's answer, the `_build` output should probably never be committed in the first place, rendering any EOL issues irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This whole `_build/` folder is created, when I run `jb-build systemtechnik-fuer-energieeffizienz`

Then it should be ignored:

```sh
cd C:/Users/andre/Documents/GitLab/OER4EE_SYE/systemtechnik-fuer-energieeffizienz
echo build/>>.gitignore
git rm --cached -r build/
git check-ignore -v -- build/.doctrees/SYE/doctree
```

Assuming `doctree` is a file, the last `git check-ignore` command should return a .gitignore rule, and `git status` should not display it, ever.

> So it is not a submodule (in my understanding submodules have an own `.git` folder, however, inside _build/ there is no such folder)

A submodule would *not* have a .git/ subfolder, but:

- would be declared in a .gitmodules file in the parent repository root folder
- would be in `$GIT_DIR/modules/_build`, meaning under the main parent repo own `.git/modules` folder

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have commletely forgotten about this. Thanks for your answer! The problem was solved as you have proposed. I didn't want to change the `.gitignore` because I have just forked this repo (but the owner did the change) and now it works!